# Filtering a dataframe with columns containing undesired values in R

Tags: r, filter, indexing

I have a dataframe with 576 columns, among which many columns contain -999.999. I actually want to remove all those columns from my dataframe, in other words, I just want to deal with the columns that don't contain -999.999. So I used a loop that gives me TRUE/FALSE though it was intended to make all -999.999 to 'NA':

```
achem<-lapply(1:length(achem), function(i) is.na(achem[[i]])<- achem[[i]]==-999.999)
> head(achem)
[[1]]
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

... ...

[[4]]
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[22] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

[[5]]
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[19] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

... ...
```

The next step is to find the lists [[i]]s that are TRUE so that I can make a new dataframe with those columns only, so I tried this

```
lapply(1:length(achem), function(i) which(achem[[i]], isTRUE))
```

But throws an error

```
Error in arr.ind && !is.null(d <- dim(x)) : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

I tried

```
lapply(1:length(achem), function(i) which(as.logical(achem[[i]])))
```

But this is not giving me the [[i]]s that I need. Any simple solution or use of Filter function?

Comment: please use dput(sample_data) to give anyone looking at this an easily reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is (given all columns are numeric):

```
achem[!colSums(achem == -999.999)]
```

This will exclude all columns in which at least one value is equal to `-999.999`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems overly complicated.

If `achem` is truly a `data.frame` (reproducible example please!), then you can just do:

```
discardCols <- apply( achem, 2, function(x) any(x==-999.99) )
achem <- achem[ , !discardCols ]
```